# Error con lsmeans R

Tags: r, static, statsmodels

Tengo un df como el siguiente (El real tiene más datos)

```
df1 <- data.frame(ID= c("67", "67", "91", "91", "30","30","31","31","01","01","26","35","35"),
                    tto= c("pozos","pozos","CTR","CTR","CTR","CTR,"LN","LN","GR","GR","CL","LN","LN"),
                  MET = c("19.4","10.86","18.08","15.56","15.51","15.33","12.23","20.28","19.98","13.22","35.46","22.20","45.90"),
                  PV = c("3","3","3","2","2","1","3","3","3","3","1","1","2")
```

Y me interesa correr una regresión lineal para ver el efecto de las variables sobre la variable "MET", para lo que hago un modelo muy simple:

```
lm1  <- lm(MET  ~ PV + relevel(tto, ref="CTR"), data=df1)
```

Obtengo que hay un efecto de los dos

```
relevel(tt2, ref = "CTR")LN    -2.501219   3.905310  -0.640 0.522367    
relevel(tt2, ref = "CTR")CL     -2.230075   2.082050  -1.071 0.285002    
relevel(tt2, ref = "CTR")GR     -1.063843   2.055856  -0.517 0.605216    
relevel(tt2, ref = "CTR")pozos   8.956845   2.037777   4.395 1.54e-05 ***
PV22                                2.037976   1.524926   1.336 0.182435    
PV23                                4.753784   1.779036   2.672 0.007957 **
```

Pero tengo problemas al pedir las medias marginales:

```
lsmeans(lm1,"PV") #No funciona
lsmeans(lm1 ~ PV) #No funciona
lsmeans(lm1 ~ PV, data=df1) #No funciona
```

Y si cambio la variable por tto tampoco. El error que da es el siguiente:

```
Error in (function (object, at, cov.reduce = mean, cov.keep = get_emm_option("cov.keep"),  : 
  We are unable to reconstruct the data.
The variables needed are:
    tto PV
Are any of these actually constants? (specify via 'params = ')
The dataset name is:
    df1
Does the data still exist? Or you can specify a dataset via 'data = '
```

Cabe decir que mi df original y el modelo que estoy ejecutando tiene más variables, pero no consigo lo que quiero. Aclarar también que tanto tto como PV son factores. Qué debo hacer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Me parece que el problema está en los nombres de las variables.  Al hacer la recodificación para cambiar la categoría de referencia en la misma llamada al modelo  con `relevel(tto, ref="CTR")` el nombre del término dentro del objeto `lm` cambia, como puedes ver en el sumario. Allí los términos se llaman `relevel(tto, ref = "CTR")CL` y cosas por el estilo.

Ahora bien, para calcular las medias marginales hacen falta el data.frame original con los datos y allí la variable tiene su nombre original: `tt0`.

Una forma simple de solucionarlo es recodificar `tto` para cambiar el nivel de referencia directamente en el data.frame.

Algo así:

```
library(lsmeans)
df1 <- data.frame(ID= c("67", "67", "91", "91", "30","30","31","31","01","01","26","35","35"),
                 tto= factor(c("pozos","pozos","CTR","CTR","CTR","CTR","LN","LN","GR","GR","CL","LN","LN")),
              MET = c("19.4","10.86","18.08","15.56","15.51","15.33","12.23","20.28","19.98","13.22","35.46","22.20","45.90"),
              fc = factor(c("3","3","3","2","2","1","3","3","3","3","1","1","2")))

#Aquí asignas el cambio de categoría de referencia en el data.frame
df1$tto <- relevel(df1$tto, ref="CTR")

#Y en el modelo usas el nombre de variable directamente

lm1  <- lm(MET  ~ PV + tto, data=df1)              

lsmeans(lm1,"PV")
```

Este es el resultado de `lsmeans`

```
 PV lsmean   SE df lower.CL upper.CL
 1    22.5 5.89  6     8.10     36.9
 2    31.5 6.27  6    16.11     46.8
 3    18.6 4.14  6     8.44     28.7

Results are averaged over the levels of: tto 
Confidence level used: 0.95
```

Comment: mil gracias! definir el relevel fuera del modelo es la clave.